# How do I hide submenus from the top menu bar?

Tags: wp-query, menus, sub-menu

My website is wiki-style and has a lot of pages that should only be reached through links on other pages. Having these all accessible from the top menu bar under their respective headings leads you from dropbox to dropbox as each page has more subpages- a huge inconvenience.
 I've managed to hide these in computer view by creating a 'dummy menu'. I added a '-' to either side of my menu bar so it looks like part of the design, when actually they were nameless menus under which I listed all my pages. As long as people didn't click on them, they couldn't tell.
 It worked fine until I realized the menu bar looked different in mobile view- completely collapsed, and when you uncollapsed it you got the full list of menus and submenus covering your entire screen- including my five-mile-long list of pages under the dummy menus. It takes forever to scroll down to the actual article.
 The only 'hide' options I've found so far makes the page completely inaccessible, even through my links. Is there another way to decide which pages are visible through the menu bar? One that will allow 'hidden' pages to still be reached through links?

Comment: Not clear can you please provide more descrption

Comment: It depends completely on the theme. Most use WP Menus where you can un-check a box that says something about automatically adding new pages. If your theme does not use a WP Menu but instead something like `wp_list_pages`, you will need to create a child theme and insert your own menu instead - one that does not list out all the subpages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide sub menus all you need to do is not have them in the first place.  Try going to the admin panel's menus section and just remove the unwanted sub menus from the menu itself.